# Service injected to component are undefined outside constructor

Tags: angular, angular-services

So I've got a weird problem I'm trying to inject some services into component but some of them are undefined when I want to use it on a function.

I have used these service on other component before and there's no problem. Also I already add keyword "public" or "private" on the constructor.

```
export class GeneSearchComponent {
    constructor(public router: Router,
                public clinicalFilteringService: ClinicalFilteringService,
                public searchBarService: SearchBarService ) {
                  //They all are defined within constructor
                  console.log(this.clinicalFilteringService);
                  console.log(this.router);
                  console.log(this.searchBarService);
    }

    test(query) {
        //clinicalFilteringService and router are undefined 
        console.log(this.clinicalFilteringService);
        console.log(this.router);
        //searchBarService is still defined
        console.log(this.searchBarService);
    }
}
```

What might cause the problem?

Edit:
So I found that changing the function into arrow function fix the problem, but I still don't know the reason why it works with arrow function and not working without it.

Comment: does all your service use `HttpClient` ?

Comment: @manish nope, none of my service use HttpClient

Comment: So changing the function into an arrow function fix the problem, not sure why it works though. If someone know, you guys can let me know.

Comment: could you please add those `edit`s too?

Comment: @user3794740 for your arrow function query : An arrow function does not have its own 'this'. The 'this' value of the enclosing lexical scope is used; arrow functions follow the normal variable lookup rules. So while searching for 'this' which is not present in current scope they end up finding 'this' from its enclosing scope.